# How would I convert a string from a single spreadsheet cell into a 2D array with GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, logging

I need to generate a table in Google Docs from a set of value pairs in a single spreadsheet cell. The values in the cell (A1) are formatted like this:

```
 ["a1","a2"],["b1","b2"],["c1","c2"]
```

I've tried:

```
testData = testSheet.getRange(1,1,1, 1).getValues().toString().split(",");
Logger.log(testData)
```

This gives me:

```
[["a1","a2"],["b1","b2"],["c1","c2"]]
```

Which looks like a 2D array to me, but when I try:

```
testDoc.insertTable(testField, testData)
```

I get the error:

```
Exception: The parameters (number,number[]) don't match the method signature for DocumentApp.Body.insertTable.
```

When I define the array manually in the function with:

```
testData = [["a1","a2"],["b1","b2"],["c1","c2"]]
```

The table is inserted as expected.

I could format the data in the cell differently, but I need all the value pairs to be in a single cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try this:

```
var testData = eval('[' + testSheet.getRange('A1').getDisplayValue() + ']');
```

Test code:

```js
var s =  '["a1","a2"],["b1","b2"],["c1","c2"]';

var testData = eval('[' + s + ']');

console.log(testData);
```

Comment: It this case `eval()` works about the same way as `JSON.stringify()`. So probably it's more safe to use the JSON approach. I'm used to use `eval()` since Extendscript (my main framework) has no native JSON parser. But we have here are a couple of pious zealots who love to downvote every single answer that mentions `eval()` function.

Comment: you mean `JSON.parse()` ? But thanks for your reference, I didn't know about it.. even if it's seems almost deprecated x)

Comment: Yep. `JSON.parse()` of course.

Answer (score 2):

#### Modification points:

- When `["a1","a2"],["b1","b2"],["c1","c2"]` is put in a cell "A1", and when the cell value is retrieved by `testSheet.getRange(1,1,1, 1).getValues()`, it is `[["[\"a1\",\"a2\"],[\"b1\",\"b2\"],[\"c1\",\"c2\"]"]]`. In this case, `[\"a1\",\"a2\"],[\"b1\",\"b2\"],[\"c1\",\"c2\"]` is the string type.

  - This can be confirmed by `JSON.stringify`.
- By this, when the cell value is retrieved by `testSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 1).getValues().toString().split(",")`, it becomes `["[\"a1\"","\"a2\"]","[\"b1\"","\"b2\"]","[\"c1\"","\"c2\"]"]`. In this case, `[\"a1\"","\"a2\"]`, `[\"b1\"","\"b2\"]` and `[\"c1\"","\"c2\"]` are the string values.

  - I thought that this is the reason for your issue.
- In order to use the cell value of `["a1","a2"],["b1","b2"],["c1","c2"]` as a 2 dimensional array, it is required to parse it.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
testData = testSheet.getRange(1,1,1, 1).getValues().toString().split(",");
```

#### To:

```
testData = JSON.parse(`[${testSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 1).getValue()}]`); // In this case, I think that `getDisplayValue()` is used instead of `getValues`.
```

- By this modification, the value of `["a1","a2"],["b1","b2"],["c1","c2"]` can be used as 2 dimensional array of `[["a1","a2"],["b1","b2"],["c1","c2"]]`.

#### Testing:

```js
const value = '["a1","a2"],["b1","b2"],["c1","c2"]';
const testData = JSON.parse(`[${value}]`);
console.log(testData)
console.log(testData[0][0]) // a1
```

#### Reference:

- [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Thanks Tanaike - this works and appreciate the explanation!